# I have lost my personal.xlsb and need to create a new one

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have searched tons of online forums for this problem and have only found where to locate my personal.xlsb folder.  However, I cannot locate the file in any of the suggested locations.  When I look in my trusted files locations, that location doesn't even exist on my machine.  So, is there a way to create a new personal.xlsb so that I start fresh?  When I try just recording a macro it says my personal.xlsb file needs to be un-hidden...

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a network PC; mine is found under C:\user\bsutton\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART

To unhide your workbook in Excel click on the View Tab  then Unhide and you should be able to continue to work on your macro.
[image]

I hope this helps,
Brad

Answer (score 0):

As the article [Copy your macros to a Personal Macro Workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566) mentioned,in Windows 10, Windows 7, and Windows Vista, this workbook is saved in the **C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Excel\XLStart folder**. However, I didn't find the folder on my computer. It should be in **C:\Users\user name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART**.

To create the personal workbook, you first need to create a macro and store it in the Personal Macro Workbook.

Here are the steps to create it:

1. Go to the **Developer** tab, and click **Record Macro**.
2. In the **Record Macro** dialog box, don't bother entering a name for the macro in the **Macro name** box. You can accept the name that Excel gives you, such as **Macro1**, since this is just a temporary macro.

When you do start creating macros of your own, you'll want to give them descriptive names, so you know what they do.

3. In the **Store Macro** in box, pick **Personal Macro Workbook** > **OK**.

This is the most important step, because if you don't already have a Personal Macro Workbook, Excel will create one for you.

4. Click **Developer** > **Stop Recording**, and Excel will have created your Personal Macro worbook.
5. When you close the workbook, you'll be prompted to save both the workbook, and the Personal Macro workbook.

For more information, please refer to [Create and save all your macros in a single workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790).